# How can I enable AnyEvent::XMPP to connect to a server using namespace prefixes in the XML stream?

Tags: perl, namespaces, xmpp, xml-namespaces, anyevent

The XMPP server I am attempting to connect to has namespace prefixes like the following *(zdef-#########)*:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="xmpp.foo.com" to="bar@xmpp.foo.com/foobar" type="result" id="1"><zdef-312457671:bind xmlns:zdef-312457671="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><jid>bar@xmpp.foo.com/foobar</jid></zdef-312457671:bind></iq>
```

And in turn, is causing the following "Expected bind and session" error:

```
<stream:error xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><zdef-312457671:connection-timeout xmlns:zdef-312457671="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams"/><zdef-647349245:text xmlns:zdef-647349245="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams" xml:lang="en">Expected bind and session</zdef-647349245:text></stream:error>
```

I am more or less using [this example](https://codehacienda.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/perl-xmpp-library-for-creating-a-chat-bot-anyeventxmpp-example/) to connect to the host. I can successfully connect to another host that does not use these namespace prefixes.

Using AnyEvent::XMPP, how can I have the script correctly process the XML stream?

Some version info:

- Perl version: v5.10.1
- AnyEvent::XMPP version: 0.53